# How to add a simple text inside a toolbar in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Hi I need add a simple text in a toolbar, the text should be between two buttons declared inside the toolbar, ANy idea how to do it? Please let me know thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here are two options you can use:

If you just want text in the center of the toolbar, use the title property:

```
{
    title: 'Some text here',
    items [/* Your buttons */]
}
```

If you want multiple text elements, a quick and dirty way of doing this is to use panels with their html property set, which will replace the created panel's content with the html:

```
{
    items [{
        // Button 1
    },{
        xtype: 'panel',
        html: 'The text you want here'
    },{
        // Button 2
    }]
}
```

If you do this, the panel may not style well, so you might have to apply some styling to the panel's `style` or `baseCls` properties to restyle it like you want.

Note that in ExtJS you can just include text in the items list and it will do what you want, but the docs don't make it clear if this works in Sencha Touch and I can't test that right now.  If that does work, it would look something like this:

```
{
    title: 'Some text here',
    items [items [{
        // Button 1
    },
    'Your text here',
    {
        // Button 2
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for add your simple text beetween two buttons on tool bar.

```
{
   xtype: 'toolbar',
   docked: 'top',
   **title: 'text you want to add here'**,
   items:[{
            xtype: 'button',
            ui: 'action',
            text: '1st button'
          },
          {
            xtype: 'button',
            ui: 'action',
            right: '0%',
            text: '2nd button',
          }
        ],
```

}

Hope this will helps you.
Thanks.